Blazor .NET 9 about:blank how can show a progress or background -something
How can I display a page- progress something when I launch a Blazor web app?
Currently whatever I do does not work. I am using .NET 9.
Any suggestions?
Updated
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Layout.MainLayout).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <div id="splash-screen" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 1000;">
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        </div>
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData"
                   DefaultLayout="@(AppState.IsLoggedIn ? typeof(Layout.MainLayout) : typeof(Layout.LandingPageLayout))"/>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not Found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.LandingPageLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

I also created a SplashLayout.razor:
<div id="splash-screen" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 1000;">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>

UPDATE
when you launch the app you see a blank page and the loading appear after 
I even added below
window.removeSplashScreen = () => {
const splashScreen = document.getElementById("splash-screen");
const appContent = document.getElementById("app-content");

if (splashScreen) {
    splashScreen.style.display = "none";
}

if (appContent) {
    appContent.style.display = "block";
}

};
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
 {
     if (firstRender)
     {
         // Remove the splash screen after the app initializes
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("removeSplashScreen");
     }
 }


"whatever I do does not work" can we see a bit of that code?

I have updated the question, whatever thing I tried I lost count now I always get the blank page when the blazor app starts my loading appears after - something must be done somewhere else.

So what does Home look like.  What does LandingPageLayout look like.

See the code below that adds the loading screen for Routes.razor.
Had to add @rendermode for the lifecycle events to be triggered.
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        @if (_showLoading)
        {
            <div id="splash-screen" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; z-index: 1000;">
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
            </div>
        }
        
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

@code {
    private bool _showLoading = true;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _showLoading = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
        base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}

If the purpose of adding this loading screen is because you have a long running task on your OnInitialized function, then you might want to check @attribute [StreamRendering]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-9.0#streaming-rendering
